# Passing a column result as a parameter of other datasets

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The premise of this is simple. I have 4 DataSets each with their own unique SQL select statement with a WHERE clause that looks for an @OrdersID. The initial DataSet has one parameter, a @FileNumber. The @FileNumber is a user entered parameter and the @OrdersID parameter needs to be hidden, but based on the @FileNumber of the OrdersID column from the initial select statement. How do I go about passing the result of one DataSet as a parameter to other DataSets?

For instance, this is my first DataSet...

```
SELECT
FileNumber
,OrdersID
,Field1
,Field2
,Field3
FROM 
TABLE1
WHERE 
FileNumber = @FileNumber
```

The second DataSet does NOT have a FileNumber column:

```
SELECT
,OrdersID
,Field1
,Field2
,Field3
FROM 
TABLE2
WHERE 
OrdersID = @OrdersID
```

How do I pass the OrdersID result of DataSet1 to the other DataSets? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want it for? Is it to print it in the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT OrdersID, Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM TABLE2
WHERE OrdersID in (SELECT OrdersID FROM TABLE1 WHERE FileNumber = @FileNumber);
```